# Laravel 5.3 Fill Eloquent model with data from API on call

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am creating service with Mangopay API, this payment system stores user legal info in they own models. So I want to make Eloquent model with only id of API user and fill my model with data from API once it called with relation or directly, how can I do this trick?

### UPDATE 1

[This is API example](https://docs.mangopay.com/endpoints/v2.01/users#e255_create-a-natural-user)

Whe I want to access API data, I should just get $user->my_api_model and will get object or eloquent model with filled data from API.

I just don't know - when hook method to make a call and fill data from API.

Comment: Can you give an example?

Comment: I also want to know the best way to do this. I just started working on an app that will call an API and get a few thousand customers in a json object. I want all of those to go into a model in a way that is at least similar to using a database table.

Comment: As a theory - use custom connection driver as gate to API, like done in extension for mongoDb but I am still investigating this way.

Comment: Have you thought of a way to do this yet? I've been trying to accomplish something very similar lately.

Comment: Nope, I do not get the goal...

Answer (score -1):

Just create your model and put the data as in a normal model:

In your model:

```
class Payer extends Model {
   protected $table = 'payers';
   protected $primaryKey = 'payer_id';
   protected $incrementing = false;
}
```

In your controller:

```
$payer = new Payer();
$payer->payer_id = $apiResponse->payerId; 
$payer->amount = $apiResponse->amount;
$payer->currency = $apiResponse->currency;
```

This is just an example but you can take this as an idea for your model.

Comment: This is not what I want, main scope is: when i calling $user->my_api_model, I should recieve MyApiModel instance but with data from table my_api_models I need to make API call to mangopay and fill data from api responce to model, like it is model properties.